# Secondary reason for shortened Shmoneh Esrei on Shabbos?

Tags: tefilla, shabbat, shemoneh-esrei

The main view for why we shorten the Shmoneh Esrei on Shabbos is that we do not want to focus on the mundane, but rather the holiness of the day.

However, I do remember hearing that the other reason for the shortened Shmoneh Esrei is that the Rabbis wanted people to make kiddush as soon as possible. Is this a valid (secondary) reason? If so, can it be found anywhere?

Comment: "The main view for why we shorten the Shmoneh Esrei on Shabbos is that we do not want to focus on the mundane, but rather the holiness of the day." I've never heard of this before. How do you know this is the "main" view? Also, I think "secondary source" has a different meaning than how you're using it. I think you mean "secondary reason".

Comment: Perhaps the other idea youre thinking of is the general prohibition on making personal requests on Shabbat?

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard of the first reason. The reason the *gemarra* gives is similar to your second reason, which is probably what you are thinking of, although it's phrased differently than you bring it:

[**Berachos**](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.21a.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he) 21a

> הָתָם גַּבְרָא בַּר חִיּוּבָא הוּא, וְרַבָּנַן הוּא דְּלָא אַטְרְחוּהוּ מִשּׁוּם כְּבוֹד שַׁבָּת
>
> There, on Shabbat, the individual is one who is obligated and should actually recite all eighteen blessings, and it is the Sages who did not impose upon him in deference to [the honor of] Shabbat and instituted an abridged formula.

If you understand כבוד שבת/the honor of Shabbos as meaning saying Kiddush quickly, then it's the same as what you heard. However, I'm personally not sure what it means they shortened *shemoneh esrei* for the honor of Shabbos. I wouldn't think it means so you can make Kiddush quickly.

Comment: Considering the correct way to daven is to take three hours over each tefilla. One to prepare one to daven and one to reflect. That would take six hours of the day. Which is a large part of shabbos. I suppose with a shortened version the preparation and reflection are also less.